# jQuery find id then do action

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, menu

I am trying to make this little code work. I have a normal drop-down menu and I want to turn it into a drop-down list (select).

The normal menu has a "tm_active" id attached to show which page you are on. I want to use jquery and find this id, then when page loads to select the right item according to what page you are on (not the first item in the list).

What am I doing wrong guys?
Thank you.

```
$('table.topMenu tr').each(function(){
var list=$(this),
    select=$(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide()).change(function(){
  window.location.href=$(this).val();
});
$('>td a', this).slice(2).each(function(){
  var option=$(document.createElement('option'))
   .appendTo(select)
   .val(this.href)
   .html($(this).html());
  if($(this).attr('id') === 'tm_active'){
    option.attr('selected','selected');
  }
});
list.remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="top">
<a href="#">Section 1</a>
<div class="sub">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
<td class="top" id="tm_active">
<a href="#">Section 2</a>
<div class="sub">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
<td class="top">
<a href="#">Section 3</a>
<div class="sub">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Your table is missing the class "topMenu" on your example I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the id of the anchor tag you should check the parent td:

```
$(this).parent().attr('id') === 'tm_active'
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9KTgF/1/)